# TFS 2010 publish to specific location

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

Need help with TFS Build.

My situation is that I have no control over the IIS boxes and the dev/test sites will not change with each build.

Can some one walk through how to create a solution(sln) build WF that copies/drops a published website.  I'm struggling with just getting the drop going to a UNC directory without all of the sub folders and how to pre-compile / publish is completely eluding me.

thank you

Comment: Do you a have build process running at all yet?